# Type of floor to use for a three season porch

Tags: engineered-flooring

I am installing a three season porch.  It will be well insulated and have energy efficient windows. The floors will not get wet.  I wanted to put pergo floors down, but Home Depot tells me they can warp because of the change in temperature.  What should I use that would be most like wood?

Comment: What range of temperature swings are you anticipating? Is this area heated or cooled to any extent?

Answer (score 1):

Vinyl plank flooring is very durable, attractive, and moves less than wood-based products. It comes in many styles, some of which very convincingly emulate natural wood through color and texture.

Just this past weekend I helped my brother install some in his home. It had built-in flexible underlayment, was very easy to cut (simple crosscuts are score-and-snap), and looked absolutely beautiful. Seams were dead tight and the product claims complete water resistance. Judging by the fit and feel of the material, I can't say I don't believe them.

Quality varies with brand, of course. Do your research and read objective reviews.

Comment: Would have said the same thing, but isherwood is so quick...  I lived in an apartment with this stuff, and liked it a lot.  Everyone thought it was wood by looking at it. Since it was laid on concrete it did have a different feel when you stepped on it, but not a bad feel like laminate.

Comment: Right. This stuff wasn't "clicky" at all when walking on it. It had a rich, damped feel and sound.